# How to use the mean-token package from MEAN.io correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mean-stack, mean.io

I'm using MEAN.io for developing a project and I'm trying to get the mean-token package to run.

I've followed up the main video from the Mean.io documentation, where they explain superficially how to use it. Well, I've added the "mean-token" attribute to a html tag to make it editable but the value showed is just "0" (zero). And in addition, although I can see the input text, I cannot write anything.

For instance:

```
<h1 class="title" mean-token="profile-name">{{ character.name }} {{ character.surname }}</h1>
```

In theory, this h1 should show the values from character.name and character.surname, but instead it just shows "0" (zero).

I went to `/admin/tokens` to create the token manually and afterwards I added its value `{{character.name}} {{character.surname}}` as I saw in the video. But it doesn't still work.

Where can I find more (and better) documentation?
Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty new to MEAN stuff too, but I'm wondering if you have tried to see what happens if you only use the name OR the surname. Does the problem have anything to do with the interaction between those two things?